# Is it possible to create access point on a laptop, which is connected to router with WiFi?

Tags: wireless-access-point

Laptop #1 is connected to the router via WiFi. Laptop #2 is too far away from router to be able to connect to them. I can create a access point or Ad-hoc if I am connected to the router via wired network. But Laptop #1 is not connected to router via cable, but via WiFi. Is it somehow possible to create acces point or Ad-hoc on computer, which is connected to router via Wireless? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I've already did that with friend, but with Windows. Laptops are on win or ubu?

Comment: Ubuntu, off course, otherwise I wouldn't ask this on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it is not possible to do this unless you have two wireless cards. For example, you could get a USB receiver for your wifi and then use the built-in WiFi card to create an ad hoc network.

I am not aware of any wireless cards that allow you to create an ad hoc network while connected to another network.

Another option would be to go with a wireless repeater (I've seen them as low as $60 USD) and they work quit well. Just place it towards the end of your network's range and they will rebroadcast the signal.

Comment: I have a wireless modem and a wireless router. Can I use the wireless router instead of wireless repeater? I have this wireless router: http://www.tp-link.com/products/productDetails.asp?pmodel=TL-WR642G

Comment: @kv1d4 I do not see any information on that page about being able to use that wireless router as a repeater. I do know that my Netgear WNR2000 has that functionality, but I am not sure if there are any other routers which also function as wireless repeaters.